# Unable to pass @varibale from transaction into log

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I have this code that does everything right I just can not pass @new_spec_id value into write_MySQL_log. 
Current code just writes @new_spec_id into log function. Witch is totally strange as I am passing the @new_spec_id value correctly into other query's. If I change it into $spec_id same thing. It just writes it as text $spec_id.

I have similar thing on other pages and I can pass the $spec_id into log.

```
mysqli_query($con,"START TRANSACTION");

     $a1 = "SELECT @new_spec_id:=COALESCE(MAX(spec_id),0) FROM SPEC;";
     $query1 = mysqli_query($con, $a1);
     write_mysql_log("Izrađena specifikacija ID: @new_spec_id", $db);

     $a2 = "UPDATE SPEC SET spec_iznos = '$value' WHERE spec_id = @new_spec_id;";
     $query2 = mysqli_query($con, $a2);    

     if ($a1 and $a2) {
         mysqli_query($con,"COMMIT");
     } else {        
         mysqli_query($con,"ROLLBACK");
     };
```

I tried to define it, not working ether..

```
     $log = "@new_spec_id";
     write_mysql_log("Izrađena specifikacija ID: $log", $db);
```

**EDIT:** 
Made it work with another SELECT...

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(spec_id) AS spec_id FROM SPEC";
     $result = $con->query($sql);
   // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       write_mysql_log("Izrađena specifikacija ID: " . $row["spec_id"], $con);
```

Comment: It took me a while to figure out what you a doing if you want to write the Max id you have to fetch the result, user defined mysql variables don't work in php but of  course you can make a SELECT @new_spec_id; but hwta the use.

Comment: Shouldn't this work then: ID: $query1 ? Its not.

Comment: Made it work outside of this code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't have any direct access to SQL variables. You need to fetch the result of the query into a PHP variable.

```
mysqli_query($con,"START TRANSACTION");

$a1 = "SELECT @new_spec_id:=COALESCE(MAX(spec_id),0) AS new_spec_id FROM SPEC;";
$query1 = mysqli_query($con, $a1);
if ($query1) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
    $new_spec_id = $row['new_spec_id'];
    write_mysql_log("Izrađena specifikacija ID: $new_spec_id", $db);

    $a2 = "UPDATE SPEC SET spec_iznos = '$value' WHERE spec_id = @new_spec_id;";
    $query2 = mysqli_query($con, $a2);    
} else {
    $query2 = null;
}

if ($query1 and $query2) {
    mysqli_commit($con);
} else {        
    mysqli_rollback($con);
};
```

Comment: Doesn't work before or after your edit. But I have made and edit with my solution that works, so you don't have waste your time. But thank you for your input.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Actually I'm sorry, your solution does work, I forgot to add } else {  part. I will mark your input as answer as its correct and explaining the mistake.